# C#: get the command before pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I am working on a PowerShell Binary module in C#.
The module includes multiple Cmdlets with support for pipeline between the different Cmdlets.

I have a scenario where I want to use the input data from the pipeline ONLY if the input command (the command before the pipeline) is a specific command from my module.

How can I get the name of the command before the pipeline so only if it equals a specific string it will be used?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you mean you hav ea string of format " foo | bar" and want to return "foo". If so `string command = "foo | bar";
    string beforePipe = command.Substring(0, command.IndexOf('|')).TrimEnd(' ');
    Console.WriteLine(beforePipe); // prints foo` ??

Comment: Not exactly. My module exports 2 cmdlets: `Get-Group` and `Get-Items`. I want pipelining support so in case a user executes `Get-Group -Name TEST | Get-Item` all items in the TEST group will be returned. Both objects `Group` and `Item` has ids, so whenever the above is executed the Group id is piped to the `Get-Item` command, which treats the piped id as an `Item` id. The desired behvior is that in case the command before the pipe is `Get-Group` I would like to search for `Items` with a property of `group/id`. Maybe not the best design but I am limited to the RESTful server I work with. Thanks